# Convert arrays with values/keys in common to a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of arrays like so:

```
[[1,"A"], [1,"B"], [2,"C"], [2,"D"]]
```

I'd like to get the results into a Hash like so:

```
1 => {results => ["A","B"]}, 2 => {results => ["C","D"]}
```

I tried using the "group_by" methods and wasn't able to get it into this form. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
irb(main):001:0> a=[[1,"A"], [1,"B"], [2,"C"], [2,"D"]]
=> [[1, "A"], [1, "B"], [2, "C"], [2, "D"]]

irb(main):002:0> h={}
=> {}

irb(main):003:0> a.each { |k,v| h[k] ||= []; h[k] << v }
=> [[1, "A"], [1, "B"], [2, "C"], [2, "D"]]

irb(main):004:0> h
=> {1=>["A", "B"], 2=>["C", "D"]}
```

Or, if you really want a hashtable of hashtable with a 'result' key:

```
irb(main):003:0> a.each { |k,v| h[k] ||= {}; h[k]['result'] ||= []; h[k]['result'] << v }
=> [[1, "A"], [1, "B"], [2, "C"], [2, "D"]]
irb(main):004:0> h
=> {1=>{"result"=>["A", "B"]}, 2=>{"result"=>["C", "D"]}}
```

Comment: Your approach is right, but the result is not what was asked.

Answer (score 2):

For one-line lover:

```
a = [[1,"A"], [1,"B"], [2,"C"], [2,"D"]]
a.inject(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {"results" => []} }) { |h, e| h[e.first]["results"] << e.last; h }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want that inner 'results' word, but here's how to get what you want:

```
the_list = [[1,"A"], [1,"B"], [2,"C"], [2,"D"]]
#=> [[1, "A"], [1, "B"], [2, "C"], [2, "D"]]

by_key = the_list.group_by(&:first)
#=> {1=>[[1, "A"], [1, "B"]], 2=>[[2, "C"], [2, "D"]]}

as_result_hash = by_key.map do |key, matches|
  [key, {'results'=>matches.map(&:last) }]
end
#=> [[1, {"results"=>["A", "B"]}], [2, {"results"=>["C", "D"]}]]

final = Hash[*as_result_hash.flatten(1)]
#=> {1=>{"results"=>["A", "B"]}, 2=>{"results"=>["C", "D"]}}
```

It sounds like you already had figured out the basic usage of group_by - you can get a set of results grouped by some key.

The next step is to just map those results to the format you want. To do this, we just map the by_key dictionary, returning the original key, and the mapped results.

This returns an array, so we use `Hash[*array.flatten(1)]` to convert it back to a dictionary.

---

if you don't need the inner 'results', you can just do:

```
as_result_hash = by_key.map do |key, matches|
  [key, matches.map(&:last)]
end
#=>  [[1, ["A", "B"]], [2, ["C", "D"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,"A"], [1,"B"], [2,"C"], [2,"D"]]
Hash[a.group_by(&:first).map{ |k, v| [k, {"results" => v.map(&:last)}]}]
```